# I can't import database from scheme file in SQLite

Tags: database, sqlite

```
drop table if exists libuser;

create table libuser (
  id integer primary key,
  name string not null,
  fname string not null,
);
```

And I get:

```
kasimov$ sudo sqlite3 library.db < scheme.sql

Error: near line 2: near ")": syntax error
```

I have no idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra comma after the `fname` declaration, causing the error. Try:

```
drop table if exists libuser;
create table libuser (id integer primary key, 
                      name string not null, 
                      fname string not null);
```